# How to control music playing in service from notification and lockscreen

Tags: android

Please show me the code that controls the media player (Streaming mp3 from server) from notification and lock screen. I know that's really simple, but i don't know from where to start. I actually doesn't know more about `mediaController` ,`mediaSessionCompat` and `NotifacationCompat.MediaStyle`.

Please refer a code to do say. I just want to play/pause and icon that closes the icon.

Thank your very very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need is to register a Media Session and set a callback to receive events from the lock screen.

```
mSession = new MediaSession(this, "MusicService");
mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
```

Create a notification

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mService);
notificationBuilder
        .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
            .setShowActionsInCompactView(new int[]{playPauseButtonPosition})  // show only play/pause in compact view
            .setMediaSession(mSessionToken))
        .setColor(mNotificationColor)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setUsesChronometer(true)
        .setContentIntent(createContentIntent(description)) // Create an intent that would open the UI when user clicks the notification
        .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
        .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
        .setLargeIcon(art).build()
```

Add actions using `addAction`

```
Notification notification = createNotification();
if (notification != null) {
    mController.registerCallback(mCb);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ACTION_NEXT);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_PLAY);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_PREV);
    mService.registerReceiver(this, filter);

    mService.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    mStarted = true;
}
```

Here's a tutorial about [Android Music Player Controls on Lock Screen and Notifications](http://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/)

Comment: I have checked the link you shared but it is not help me i know how to set notifications but i don't know how to set controls on lock screen and also i want to change the lock screen background of device CHECK THIS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595575/how-to-set-this-type-of-view-for-a-notification PLEASE HELP