# How to display music player controls on lock screen

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a music player, and I would like to show the controls(Play,Pause,Next) on the lock screen.

How do I implement that?

Thank you!

Comment: is this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534482/how-to-control-music-playing-in-service-from-notification-and-lockscreen

Comment: Yes! hank you! I will take a look at it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control music playing in service from notification and lockscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534482/how-to-control-music-playing-in-service-from-notification-and-lockscreen)

Comment: No, not exactly, I actually just read that blog and I do not understand it. If you could simplify it that would be magnificent!

Comment: Could you explain what you don't understand or what doesn't work about it?